# Trying to understand that $Imm(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb R^d)\simeq Map(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb S^{d-1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, pullback

I'm looking at various seminars that Pascal Lambrechts has given about manifold calculus. One of the lectures I've found is in the following [slides](https://sma.epfl.ch/%7Ehessbell/arolla/Lambrechts.pdf) of one of his lectures, but I have problems understanding it.

In particular, I'm struggling to understand how one can achieve the result in this slide by the proof shown in it:
[image]

Here, $O_1$ and $O_2$ represent half of the northern and southern hemispheres and a bit more on the sides. They are chosen in a way that $O_1\cap O_2$ can be identified as the disjoint union of two intervals (or $\Bbb D^1\cong [-1,1]$). Below, I use the notation of $A$ and $B$, which correspond respectively to $O_1$ and $O_2$. Here's a graph that shows each element:

[image]

I just need to understand it for $V = \Bbb R^d$, so we would have the theorem

> $\operatorname{Imm}(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb R^d) \simeq \operatorname{Map}(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb S^{d-1})$

with the following diagram:

[image]

I've tried to understand the result for $d=2$, in which we can compute the pullback of $\Bbb S^1\stackrel{\Delta}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1 \stackrel{\Delta}{\longleftarrow} \Bbb S^1$. I don't know what $\Delta$ is, but I considered the diagonal of $\Bbb S^1$: $$\Delta:\Bbb S^1\to\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1,\quad x\mapsto(x,x).$$

In this case, the pullback would be $$\Bbb S^1\times_{\Delta\times\Delta}\Bbb S^1 = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1 : (x,x) = \Delta(x) = \Delta(y) = (y,y)\} = \{(x,x)\in\Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1\}.$$

But in this case, the pullback is just the diagonal of the torus, which is just a copy of $\Bbb S^1$. I don't know how to find a homotopy equivalence (or something mor powerful) from $\Bbb S^1$ to $\operatorname{Map}(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb S^1)$ to get what I'm looking for.

Could anyone please help me out understanding the proof of the Smale's theorem? Or at least, understand the case for $d = 1$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure you're correct that $\Delta$ is the notation for the diagonal map. It would also help if you could edit in a bit more explanation of the notation as well; other notation, which you might know in the context of the slides, might not be as clear here. For example, what are $O_1$ and $O_2$? What are $A$ and $B$? What does that symbol $\simeq$ represent?

Comment: Also, you write *I don't know how to go from $\Bbb S^1$ to $\operatorname{Map}(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb S^1)$*. So..... you are asking for the definition of a function $\Bbb S^1 \to \operatorname{Map}(\Bbb S^1,\Bbb S^1)$?

Comment: You need the _homotopy_ pullback, which is known to be the free loop space. It's a good exercise, actually.

Comment: @LeeMosher I just added the info. Thanks for comenting!

Comment: @JustinYoung yes, but I have no idea how to do so. Any help?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a homotopy pullback?

Comment: Just a remark: this theorem is a special case of a much more general theorem which identifies immersions from M to N with fiberwise injective bundle maps of tangent bundles (we assume $\mathrm{dim}(N)>\mathrm{dim}(N))$. In this case, since $R^n$ is contractible and $TS^1$ is trivial, the bundle maps will coincide with the fiberwise injective bundle maps $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \{*\} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ which for each $x \in S^1$ is uniquely determined by the image of $(x,1)$. Now its easy to see the bundle mapping space has the homotopy type of $\mathrm{Map}(S^1,S^{n-1})$.

Comment: @JustinYoung no, I don't. I barely know how to compute just a pullback!

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sounds interesting. Which concepts should I know beforehand to understand this result?

Comment: The proof is based on something called the h-principle which is a statement involving homotopy sheaves. It might be helpful to be familiar with homotopy limits and a little sheaf theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $\Delta:X\to X\times X$ by the fibration $X^I\to X\times X$ given by evaluation at the two endpoints. Then, a point in the pullback of the new square is given by a pair of paths $p,q: I\to X$ so that $p(0)=q(0)$ and $p(1)=q(1)$, these paths can be glued together at the ends to make free loops $S^1\to X$. This is the idea, but you may need to dig into homotopy limits/model categories a bit to understand this.